# Picture Viewer to easily copy & paste into MS Office Excel

Tags: windows, gratis, microsoft-excel, office

I need some open/free software for opening pictures with functionality to copy and paste it into another application (Excel in this case).

Currently I have to: `(1)` Right click the file > `(2)` Edit > `(3)` Ctrl+a > `(4)` Ctrl+c > `(5)` switch to Excel > `(6)` Ctrl+v (the picture is put in the A1 cell) > `(7)` Move the picture to the correct place in Excel.

I need something like: `(1)` Double click to open > `(2)` Ctrl+c > `(3)` switch to Excel > `(4)` Paste.

Comment: I would say XnView but you still have to use CTRL-A. http://www.xnview.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JPEGView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegview/) fits the bill. Once you've opened the image file with that application (I have it set as the default image viewer) you can Ctrl & C to copy, switch to Excel and paste away.

Comment: This is a great option! Really fast and very customisable!